# How to get object from ViewComponent on post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

On my razor page project, I am using a View Component as a template for listings, like so in my html:

```
@foreach (var listingItem in Model.ListingItems)
{    
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Listing", new { listingItem = listingItem })
}
```

where a ListingItem object is passed down to be displayed with the model:

```
public class ListingViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public ListingItem ListingItem { get; private set; }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(ListingItem listingItem)
    {
       return View(this);
    }
}
```

In this `Listing` view component, I have among other things a form with a post:

```
<form method="post">
// some stuff
</form>
```

So far, I am able to successfully display data and get a post. I've search for ways to pass down object from ViewComponents to Page Models on click but haven't been successful. Can this be achieved with ViewComponents or do I need to use something like partial views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've search for ways to pass down object from ViewComponents to Page Models on click.

You can try to use `asp-page` and `asp-handler` to set page and handler,so that when click button,the form data will be passed to the handler of the page.

```
 <form method="post" asp-page="xxpage" asp-handler="xxhandler">
// some stuff
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks it worked!